# Twig - use quotation mark as separator for join filter

Tags: twig, htmlspecialchars

I pass my template an array of strings which I would like to convert to a jaavascript array:

Controller file (php):

```
$myVar = array('a','b','c');
```

Desired html:

```
var myVar = ["a","b","c"];
```

I try the following code (twig):

```
var myVar = ["{{ myVar | join('","') }}"];
```

But the twig generator converts the quotation marks to html entities and this is the result:

```
var myVar = ["a&quot;,&quot;b&quot;,&quot;c"];
```

Some idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to apply the [`raw`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html) filter:

```
var myVar = ["{{ myVar | join('","') | raw }}"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Maerlyn's answer will work, however the drawback with it is that the values in the `myVar` array will be outputted raw too, which, depending on the origin of that variable, could lead to vulnerabilities in your website, such as XSS.

I found two ways to do this while maintaining the escaping on the array values. The first is using a loop with an `if` statement to check whether it's the last iteration to determine whether we need to output the "glue" used in the join or not:

```
var myVar = [{% for val in myVar %}"{{ val }}"{% if loop.last == false %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}]
```

The second way is to let PHP your PHP handle everything, including the escaping, and then output the raw string in Twig:

```
$arr = array_map(
    function($value) {
        return '"' . htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '"';
    },
    $arr
);
$myVar = '[' . implode(',', $arr) . ']';
```

Then pass the `$myVar` variable to your view, and then you can just do:

```
{{ myVar|raw }}
```