# How can I set UTF-8 in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, utf-8

I don't know what else to try; each time I render a twig template, I get those symbols:

> �

Instead of "á" for example.

Each template, extends a "base" template, which cointains:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

But that symbol is still shown. I checked sourcecode of the page rendered, and that meta tag line appears there.

Is there any global configuration I've to set to avoid this?

Thank you!

Edit: Note that I'm using TWIG. Maybe some Twig parameters are missconfigured?

[image]

Comment: Symfony2 by default uses UTF8. I guess your text editor/IDE does not save files in that encoding.

Comment: @Crozin i've added a screenshot with chrome sourcecode and netbeans code. check it out :)

Comment: Check whether UTF8 is being used in HTTP Response header. Chrome -> F12 -> Network -> reload your website -> check `Content-Type` response header from the very first response.

Comment: Finally got it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034891/how-do-you-set-the-encoding-to-utf-8-in-netbeans-6-9

It was some sort of problem with Netbeans.

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán can you please add an answer to this question how you solved it and accepts that as an aswer?

Answer (score -4):

You should use `&agrave;`, see [the html special characters](http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html)

To do this dynamically: look at the php function [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: Well, I could use "oacute" or whatever, but that's not the fact. I can't manually edit each character from website. Its a dynamic content, which may contain those kind of letters.

Comment: Using html special characters to fix a global encoding problem is not a thing to use.

Comment: Updated description with a function that does this dynamically. Normally twig does this automatically for you. however if you use the raw parameter twig doesn't do this. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557010/twig-use-quotation-mark-as-separator-for-join-filter). But that wasn't the problem too, it wa a thing with his IDE.